# Running a Junit test from Eclipse throwing No class definition found error?

Tags: eclipse

Hi I am having a Junit test class in my project .

I am trying to run unit test from the Eclipse IDE using , Debugs as >> Junit Test . However  i can see in the console it throwing an error .

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/EngineDiscoveryListener
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
```

when I perform the test from the console it is working fine

from the console when issue the command

```
mvn clean install
```

the tests are run successfully

appreciate if you can help

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the current version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it . earlier i was using junit version 5.4.0 and upgrading it to 5.8.0 it works fine